# Detecting a burst in real-time?

Tags: anomaly-detection, real-time

I'm tracking the value of a variable over time. I would like to detect if the value of the variable is bursting (having an unusual increase in it's value) in real-time. How can I do that?

Comment: TAs a simple solution, try using a moving average filter. But beware of spurious results (e.g. Yule effect) that can occur, so best try with different window sizes to see if you get consistent results.

Comment: Do you mean the cumulative moving average?

Comment: I really don't understand how to apply that to detect a burst. Can you please explain the process?

Comment: This is precisely the kind of event most quality-control systems are designed to detect.  Recognizing this, research the quality control literature and its methods.